# CSS display a text or label when hover

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a menu that when user hover into it a label or text will appear on the right side, i manage to create a simple effect using below code. but i am lost with how can i make a label appear when hover.

```css
#side-menu {
background-color : black;
color:white;
width:80px;
padding:20px;
list-style:none;
}

#side-menu:hover {
 width: 400px !important; 
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul id="side-menu">
        <li>
             <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i>     
        </li>
    </ul>
```

My goal is to display a label or text on the right side when hover, any suggestions to achieve this? this so far below is my code. thanks in advance!

```
<li><i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i> <span class='label-menu'> Product Image <span></li>

.label-menu{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can show text when the mouse hovers over the icon:

```css
span{
    display:none;
}
#side-menu {
    background-color : black;
    color:white;
    width:80px;
    padding:20px;
    list-style:none;
}

#side-menu:hover {
    width: 400px !important; 
    display:inline-block;
}
#side-menu:hover span{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="side-menu">
    <li>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i> 
            <span>Product Image</span
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick.

```css
#side-menu {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  transition: ease-in-out all .4s;
  display: table;
}

li {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.side-menu__label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: ease-in-out all .4s;
}

#side-menu:hover {
  width: 400px;
}

#side-menu:hover .side-menu__label {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul id="side-menu">
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="side-menu__label">Hello World</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see code

```css
#side-menu {
background-color : black;
color:white;
width:180px;
padding:20px;
list-style:none;
position: relative;
}

#side-menu:hover {
 display:inline-block;
}


.label-menu,
#side-menu i{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#side-menu:hover .label-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
.label-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul id="side-menu">
<li><i class="fa fa-image fa-2x"></i> <span class='label-menu'> Product Image </span></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: I was trying to make the text appear inside the li, but this code is great.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a span to your list item and show it when you hover like this:

```css
#side-menu {
background-color : black;
color:white;
width:150px;
padding:20px;
list-style:none;
}
#side-menu li span.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#side-menu li span.fa:hover ~ span {
 display:inline-block;
}
#side-menu li span.fa ~ span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul id="side-menu">
        <li>
             <span class="fa fa-image fa-2x"></span><span>your Text here</span>     
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to achieve this is by adding a simple static text in CSS. Eg.

```css
#side-menu {
background-color : black;
color:white;
width:80px;
padding:20px;
list-style:none;
}
#side-menu:hover {
 width: 400px !important; 
 display:inline-block;
}
#side-menu li:hover:after {
 content: ">> Hovering >>"; /* You can add simple static text in CSS as well. */
    position: inline-block;

}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul id="side-menu">
        <li>
             <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i>     
        </li>
        <li>
             <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i>     
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This is the quickest way to add tiny DOM using ::after and ::before pseudo elements.

For more control over the text content you can use normal elements as shown below

```css
#side-menu {
background-color : black;
color:white;
width:80px;
padding:20px;
list-style:none;
}

#side-menu:hover {
 width: 400px !important; 
 display:inline-block;
}
#side-menu li span {
   visibility: hidden;
   display:inline-block;
}
#side-menu li:hover span {
 visibility: visible;

}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul id="side-menu">
        <li>
             <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i>
             <span> Label 1</span>     
        </li>
        <li>
             <i class="fa fa-image fa-2x" style="margin-left:17px;"></i>
             <span> Label 2</span>     
        </li>
    </ul>
```